# How to read header value from feign Response

Tags: spring-boot, header, response, feign

i am using spring boot to call a openfeign client and from the Response of that feign i need to extract some header values.how can i do that.
can anybody help please.
just help me wheather we can do that or not!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do that. With Feign, we usually declare our interface with the method returning our class and Feign will automatically de-serialise the response from JSON into our POJO.

Here is the interface (operation):

```
@FeignClient(name = "library-book-service")
@RequestMapping("books")
public interface BookClient {

    @GetMapping
    public List<Book> getBooks(
        @RequestParam("page") Optional<Integer> pageNum,
        @RequestParam("size") Optional<Integer> pageSize,
        @RequestParam("reader") Optional<Long> readerId);
}
```

And then you can use the feign client like this:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BookService {
    private final @NonNull BookClient bookClient;

    public List<Book> retrieveBooks(
        Optional<Integer> pageNum, 
        Optional<Integer> pageSize, 
        Optional<Long> readerId) {

            return bookClient.getBooks(pageNum, pageSize, readerId);
    }
```

However,  in order to have access to the response headers, you need to declare your methods to return `feign.Response`.

```
import feign.Response;

@FeignClient(name = "library-book-service")
@RequestMapping("books")
public interface BookClient {

    @GetMapping
    public Response getBooks(
        @RequestParam("page") Optional<Integer> pageNum,
        @RequestParam("size") Optional<Integer> pageSize,
        @RequestParam("reader") Optional<Long> readerId);
}
```

This way you can have access to the response **body** and **headers**:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BookService {
    private final @NonNull BookClient bookClient;
    private final @NonNull ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public List<Book> retrieveBooks(
        Optional<Integer> pageNum, 
        Optional<Integer> pageSize, 
        Optional<Long> readerId) {

          var response = bookClient.getBooks(pageNum, pageSize, readerId);
          if (response == null) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
          }

          // retrieve body
          var books = objectMapper.readValue(
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.body().asInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)),
            new TypeReference<List<Book>>(){});

          // retrieve headers
          Map<String, Collection<String>> headers = response.headers();
          // ... do whatever you need with the headers

          return books;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `import feign.Response` as a response like:

```
@PostMapping("/test")
Response test(@RequestBody TestRequest testRequest);
```

then you can reach http header

```
response.headers().get(HEADER_NAME).toString();
```

if you want get body in this case you have to some json-string manipulation by use `response.body()` [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35972774/10372136) may help you for this

Comment: Issue with this is, it does not go through error decoder. It will bypass.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you want to retrieve both the (deserialized) response body as well as the response headers. In that case, returning a `ResponseEntity` is ideal because it includes both.

```java
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;

@FeignClient(name = "HttpStatusClient", url = "https://httpstat.us")
interface HttpStatusClient {
    record HttpStatus(int code, String description){}

    @GetMapping(path = "/200", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> twoHundred();
}
```

Comment: I am using plain feign and not spring cloud one. Using Feign builder etc. If I do just Response as return type, it does work but it bypasses errordecoder. Do you know achieve same with plain Feign ?