# Feign: How to extract a header value in the response of a post?

Tags: rest, kotlin, spring-cloud-feign, feign, openfeign

I have the following problem I'm trying to solve using Feign:

1. I do a POST call to a service.
2. I then need to extract a value out of the response header (a correlation id) that I need to save in a database.

The only way I found to do this was by returning a `feign.Response` object as specified here: [How to read header value from feign Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73635986/how-to-read-header-value-from-feign-response)

So I implemented the following client (in Kotlin) and the service calling this client can extract the the header value from the `feign.Response` that is returned. I'd prefer not to return the `feign.Response` to the calling service but I can't see another way.

```kotlin
@FeignClient(
    name = "doSomething",
    url = "\${doSomething.baseUrl}",
    configuration = [DoSomethingClientConfiguration::class]
)

interface DoSomethingClient {

    @PostMapping(value = ["/create-something"], consumes = [APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
    fun createSomething(thingToCreate: ThingToCreate) : feign.Response

}
```

The **issue** I have is the following: Due to the fact that the `createSomething(...` method now returns a `feign.Response`, the default `ErrorDecoder` and `Retryer.Default` defined in my `DoSomethingClientConfiguration` gets by-passed and the `feign.Response` (which is a `404` in this specific case), gets returned to the calling service to deal with it which is not desirable.

The **solution** I am looking for is a smarter way to return a `feign.Response` header value without having to return the `feign.Response` itself which causes it to by-pass the default behaviour.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own decoder and "Response" class or use one from spring-cloud-starter-openfeign org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity

[Feign retryer not called when when method is returning feign.Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76070429/feign-retryer-not-called-when-when-method-is-returning-feign-response/76070595#76070595)

Answer (score 0):

```
package backend.core.circuitbreak;

import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;

import feign.RequestInterceptor;
import feign.RequestTemplate;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class FeignRequestInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor
{

    @PostConstruct
    private void init()
    {
        log.info("Interceptor that copies the header of a request was initialized");
    }

    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate)
    {
        ServletRequestAttributes requestAttributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
                .getRequestAttributes();

        if (requestAttributes == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        HttpServletRequest request = requestAttributes.getRequest();
        Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
        while (headerNames.hasMoreElements())
        {
            String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
            String headerValue = request.getHeader(headerName);
            log.debug("Copy header {} {}", headerName, headerValue);
            requestTemplate.header(headerName, headerValue);
        }
    }
}
```