# Feign retryer not called when when method is returning feign.Response

Tags: java, feign

When executing Request using Feign client which is returning feign.Response, error decoder or retryer is not called.

For example, usage of this method is not going through error decoder or retryer

```
@RequestLine("GET")
feign.Response execute();
```

When methods returns String, retryer and error decoder is called

In feign.ResponseHandler there is "special" way to handle feign.Response class

```
  public Object handleResponse(String configKey,
                               Response response,
                               Type returnType,
                               long elapsedTime)
      throws Exception {
    try {
      response = logAndRebufferResponseIfNeeded(configKey, response, elapsedTime);
      if (returnType == Response.class) {
        return disconnectResponseBodyIfNeeded(response);
      }

      final boolean shouldDecodeResponseBody = (response.status() >= 200 && response.status() < 300)
          || (response.status() == 404 && dismiss404 && !isVoidType(returnType));

      if (!shouldDecodeResponseBody) {
        throw decodeError(configKey, response);
      }
```

Is there a way to get Response headers and still use standard feign retry/error decoder logic ? Or I'm just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use as Response org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity from spring-cloud-starter-openfeign

```
Feign.builder()
   .decoder(new ResponseEntityDecoder(new Decoder.Default()))
```

Or Implement similar solution by themselves